# centered 2x2 grid

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to put together a page that has a grid of four square divs in the center. Here's what I've got, I think you'll be able to see what I intended to happen. What am I missing here to make the positioning work as it should?

http://jsfiddle.net/LKfd4/

**HTML**

```
<div id='main-container'>
 <div class='box' id='topleft'></div>
 <div class='box' id='topright'></div>
 <div class='box' id='bottomleft'></div>
 <div class='box' id='bottomright'></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-container{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:980px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}

.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
    border:2px solid #696969;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

#topleft{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:-110px;
}
#topright{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#bottomleft{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#bottomright{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:-110px;
}
```

Comment: Can your markup change or can you only change the CSS?

Comment: anything can change, this was just a first draft of the concept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `position: relative;` from `#topleft`, `#topright`, `#bottomleft`, `#bottomright`. And add `position: absolute;` to `.box`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G85fM/

udpated jsfiddle (with regards to @Neils comment): http://jsfiddle.net/G85fM/1/

Comment: Bah, you beat me to it, but while you're here I might as well suggest moving the top and left styles to .box too.

Comment: ahh, yes. Wasn't paying to much attention to anything besides the position style. Noted and taking care of with updated fiddle.